# How to open my files by double click

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.2, intellij-14, android-studio-2.1

Android Studio was working fine, and unexpectedly, each time I do single click on any class android studio immediately opens it.

I googled how to disable this options and one suggestion was to change the key map..i did that as shown int he picture below..I changed the action of "Jump To Source" to be done by single click..then I clikced ok...but that did not solve the problem

please let me know how to open my file by double click not by single click

**image**

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you activated the *Autoscroll to source* option in the project view? This will always open a clicked source file.

[image: autoscroll to source option]

Comment: thanks..thats what i ve been looking for....but please i ahve a nother small question..is there any way to goto the source file which is currently open in the tab?? for example, i have 5 opened tabs in android studio and i want to goto the class which is currently opened in the tab number 3..how to do so please

Comment: I don't know any solution but IntelliJ does not always append tabs (depending on your preferences). So the best solution might be to use CTRL / CMD + E to switch between the recently opened files.

Answer (score 1):

For your secondary question: clicking on this icon will highlight the class that is in the current tab in the treeview

[image]